# How do I mark a delegate as not being serializable or ignore it?

Tags: c#, serialization, reflection

My current implementation goes through all classes in a specific project, fishes out all of them that I've marked as being serializable using the `SerializableAttribute` and creating different XML schema files based on some other rules and deserializing manually creates XML files. Everything worked fine and well until I added the first delegate to my project like so:

```
public delegate void CharacterStoreChanged();
```

Strangely enough the backing classes the compiler generates from delegates are automatically marked as being serializable as I've commented in the following code:

```
    private static Type[] GetDatafileTypes()
    {
        Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetAssembly( typeof ( Importer ) );
        return
            assembly.GetTypes()
                .Where( t => t.IsSerializable && t.IsPublic )
                .ToArray(); //contains the delegate's backing class since it's public and automatically serializable
    }

    private static T Deserialize<T>( string filePath )
    {
        Type[] dataFileTypes = GetDatafileTypes();

        XmlSerializer x = new XmlSerializer( typeof ( T ), dataFileTypes ); //Fails because we provide a class in dataFileTypes that doesn't have an empty constructor :-(

        return (T)x.Deserialize( new XmlTextReader( filePath ) );
    }
```

I would like to ignore the Delegate (and all that may come in the future) but I'm not sure how. I can't mark it with `[NonSerializable]` or `[XmlIgnore]` since those cannot be applied to "declaration types" and there doesn't seem to be a `IsDelegate`method on the `TypeInfo` I could use to filter them.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could check [IsAssignableFrom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with `typeof(Delegate)` to see whether the type is a delegate.

```
private static Type[] GetDatafileTypes()
{
    Type delegateType = typeof(Delegate);
    Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetAssembly( typeof ( Importer ) );
    return
        assembly.GetTypes()
            .Where( t => t.IsSerializable && t.IsPublic && !delegateType.IsAssignableFrom(t))
            .ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Once again I was thinking way too complicated.